# Excel 2013 Formula

Tags: excel

I want to add a caveat to the end of the following formula.

**`=IF(C9="Post 2000",1, IF(C9="1991-2000",1.19,IF(C9="1951-1990",1.29,IF(C9="Pre 1951",1.59))))`**

In the part dealing with Pre 1951, I want to add a caveat that says, if C16>=2500, use 1.64 instead of 1.59.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
=IF(C9="Post 2000",1, IF(C9="1991-2000",1.19,IF(C9="1951-1990",1.29,IF(C9="Pre 1951",IF(C16>"2500",1.64,1.59),"FalsePartNeeded"))))
```

Comment: You still need a `False` part on the last statement, if `C9` doesn't equal `Pre 1951`.